# Ajax-update only a component attribute, not the whole component nor its children

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, attributes, conditional-rendering

I would like to know if for JSF components and using PPR it is possible to update only some attributes of the component, and not updating the child components.

For example if I have a component with a title attribute and some child components and want only the title to be updated but not the whole component and its children.

In the example of a chart library I could have something like this :

```
<xxx:myChart title="Title">
    <xxx:ChartData x="" y=""/>
    <xxx:zoomBehavior />
</xxx:myChart>
```

I would like to show/hide the title after I have zoomed, scrolled on the chart.  When using Partial Rendering on the chart it will reinitialize its children with default values.

How to avoid that ?